# Is it possible to use 2 Mathematical Conditions in a If Statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, blackjack, gambling

I'm creating a blackjack program. I need to check `if the dealer's hand is greater than the players hand` `and also less then 21.`

*Variables*

```
dValue1 is the dealer's first card
dValue2 is the dealer's second card
pValue1 is the player's first card
pValue2 is the player's second card
```

I tried doing this :

```
if(dValue1 + dValue2 > pValue1 + pValue2 && < 21)
```

But I received the following errors :
Type mismatch : cannot convert from int to boolean.
The operator && is undefined for the argument types boolean, int.

If anyone could possible suggest another way to do this, or if I'm just simply making a syntax mistake, I'd really appreciate it.

**TO CLARIFY:** I wanted to check if the value of the dealer's card is greater then the player's cards, but also less than 21.

Comment: Probably `... && dValue1 + dValue2 < 21)`, but it would help if you gave a [mcve] including the language you were using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to split condition into two.

```
if ((dValue1 + dValue2) > (pValue1 + pValue2) && (dValue1 + dValue2) < 21)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I was pretty sure I just had the syntax wrong. Preciate the help mate!